# Lua Date Format and Comparison

Tags: lua

How do you compare dates with lua?  What is the best string format for dates?  Should I store dates in epoch?  I am looking for performance ...

Is the best way os.difftime?

Comment: os.difftime is the way I go about it when I want to see the time between dates. Look it up on the lua users wiki for an excellent example.

Comment: @Josh any recommendation of the format that I pass around?  I am defining a data model across a couple of languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are asking several things, so here are my answers:

> Should I store dates in epoch?

In general yes, the best way to store the dates is by using epochs, as returned by [os.time](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.time)

> How do you compare dates with lua?

It depends on how you want to "compare" them.

If you just want to know which one is newer/older, then the easiest fastest thing is storing them as "epochs" and then doing `date1 < date2`; since both dates are just numbers, this is both performant and clean.

If you want to know how many months/days/years have passed between two given dates, that's a bit more complex. You will need a code similar to this:

```
diff = os.date("*t", os.difftime(date1, date2))
```

On that example, the returned `diff` is a table similar to `{year=1, month=5, day=1, hour=2, min=3, sec=40 ...}`

> I am looking for performance ...

If you are using `os.date()` too often to transform epochs into dates (for example, for printing) then you might want to "cache" the year, month, etc information in a table, so you don't have to call it again and again. But do this only if you experience a bad performance; **don't pre-optimize**.

> What is the best string format for dates?

That completely depends on how you want to use them. For example, if your app interacts with another service that expects a certain date format, it makes sense to use that format in all your app.

If you have no particular need to use a format, then one candidate is (`%x`):

```
os.date("%x", date) -- 09/16/1998 (for example)
```

The string that gives you depends on the computer's locale. This might or might not be desirable.

If you want the representation to be the same across all computers, independently of their locale, you might want to try a standard format, like [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
os.date("%Y-%m-%d", date) -- returns "1998-09-16" in all computers
```

This format has lots of advantages; the most obvious one is that dates sorted out alphabetically are also sorted out chronologically. But the most important one is that a lot of software out there is prepared to read/use it.

You can find more information about dates in [Programming in Lua, Section 22.1 - Date and Time](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) and in the [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial).